# A ballad or prose?

Tags: fiction, style, fantasy, poetry

I am now planning to start with the third chapter of my novel. I got an interesting idea to write it as a ballad. But I am much better with prose. Will I better off if I continue writing prose or should I experiment with a ballad?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Writers.  I'm putting this on hold for now as you haven't told us enough to do more than offer unsupported opinions.  What is the overall structure of your novel?  How do you envision the ballad working within that?  Are there other musical/poetic motifs?  Will ballads be significant elsewhere?  Are you using it to convey events, provide insight into a particular character (like the ballad-writer), or something else?  Please [edit] to make this question more objectively answerable.  Thanks.  You might want to check out our short [tour] if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have written first two chapters in prose, you should stick with prose for them. However, as you have a strong urge to write a ballad, I would say that you must give that a try. If you could manage to write it successfully, you could start the third chapter in prose and then introduce the ballad in pieces along with the prose.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a deadline? If not,  there's little downside to experimenting with a ballad form. Might be harder to get traditionally published,  but still: I'd say if you've got the urge to give a ballad a shot, go for it. If it doesn't work so well nothing would stop you redoing it in prose.  You could also do it the other way - keep going so you don't break the prose, but then have fun trying it out as a ballad after and see how you like it.

But I'd definately encourage giving it a shot.